# CombineFn for Python dict in Apache Beam pipeline

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've been experimenting with the Apache Beam SDK in Python to write data processing pipelines.

My data mocks IoT sensor data from a Google PubSub topic that streams JSON data like this:

```json
{"id": 1, "temperature": 12.34}
{"id": 2, "temperature": 76.54}
```

There are IDs ranging from `0` to `99`. Reading the JSON into a Python dict is no problem.

I created a custom `CombineFn` to process by `CombinePerKey`. I hoped that the output of my accumulator would be the calculations, grouped by the respective `id` fields from the dictionaries in the PCollection.

However, when the `add_input` method is called, it only receives the **string** `temperature` instead of the whole dictionary. I also did not find any reference to tell `CombinePerKey` which key (`id` field in my case) I want it to group data.

Maybe I also misunderstood the concept of CombinePerKey and CombineFn. I'd appreciate any help or hint on this. Maybe someone has an example for processing JSON batches with ID based grouping? Do I have to convert the dictionary into something else?

Comment: May you add an example of payload for the expected list please ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either adjust your `CombineFn` or (what I would recommend) keep the `CombineFn` as generic as possible and map the input of the `CombinePerKey` accordingly. I have made a short examples of both cases below using [this official beam example](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/combineperkey/#example-5-combining-with-a-combinefn).

Specific `CombineFn`:

```
import apache_beam as beam

class SpecificAverageFn(beam.CombineFn):
  def create_accumulator(self):
    sum = 0.0
    count = 0
    accumulator = sum, count
    return accumulator

  def add_input(self, accumulator, input):
    sum, count = accumulator
    extracted_input = input['temperature'] # <- this is a dict, you need to create custom code here
    return sum + extracted_input, count + 1

  def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
    # accumulators = [(sum1, count1), (sum2, count2), (sum3, count3), ...]
    sums, counts = zip(*accumulators)
    # sums = [sum1, sum2, sum3, ...]
    # counts = [count1, count2, count3, ...]
    return sum(sums), sum(counts)

  def extract_output(self, accumulator):
    sum, count = accumulator
    if count == 0:
      return float('NaN')
    return sum / count

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  (
    pipeline
    | "mock input" >> beam.Create([
     {'id': 1, 'temperature': 2},
     {'id': 2, 'temperature': 3},
     {'id': 2, 'temperature': 2}
    ])
    | "add key" >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x['id'], x))
    | beam.CombinePerKey(SpecificAverageFn())
    | beam.Map(print)
  )
```

Generic `Combinefn`:

```
import apache_beam as beam

class GenericAverageFn(beam.CombineFn):
  # everything as SpecificAverageFn, except add_input:
  def add_input(self, accumulator, input):
    sum, count = accumulator
    return sum + input, count + 1


with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  iot_data = (
    pipeline
    | "mock input" >> beam.Create([
     {'id': 1, 'temperature': 2},
     {'id': 2, 'temperature': 3},
     {'id': 2, 'temperature': 2}
    ])
    | "add key" >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x['id'], x))
  )

  # repeat below for other values
  (
    iot_data
    | "extract temp" >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1]['temperature']) 
    | beam.CombinePerKey(AverageFn())
    | beam.Map(print)
  )
```

Both approaches return

```
(1, 2.0)
(2, 2.5)
```